# Bind key to a prefix in evil

Tags: evil

I have the following definition in my `init.el`:

```el
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "SPC j") #'evilem-motion-next-line)
```

This works if I want to do <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, but I'd like to be able to do <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> as well. (Here, <kbd>SPC</kbd> is meant to take the place of the prefix argument or "count", which can come in either location. see [evil-easymotion](https://github.com/PythonNut/evil-easymotion) for a description of its behavior).

The naive solution

```el
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC d") (kbd "d SPC"))
```

Does not work for the same reason described in [Emacs bind key to prefix](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/emacs-bind-key-to-prefix). The solution to that question doesn't work for me because there is no prefix command to bind to, as all commands are hidden behind `evil-delete`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, not sure if it will work.

```
(defun simulate-key-press (key)
  "Return a command that pretends KEY was presssed.
KEY must be given in `kbd' notation."
  `(lambda () (interactive)
     (setq prefix-arg current-prefix-arg)
     (setq unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence (read-kbd-macro ,key)))))

(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC d") (simulate-key-press "d SPC"))
```

Comment: This is ridiculously awesome.

Comment: Ah. One caveat: this doesn't work for multiple keys, as in `SPC gu` ==> `gu SPC`.

Comment: @PythonNut Did you try writting it as `SPC g u` (with a space between the g and the u)?

Comment: No, but even with that I get `user-error: Key sequence contains no complete binding`.

Comment: Alas, can't win them all. :(

Answer (score 1):

So you want `SPC` to be a prefix key, which means binding it to a keymap. You want `d` to be bound in that map, and you want it too to be a prefix key, which means that you want to bind `d` to another keymap.

I don't see *why* you would want to do this, but if that's what you want to do then that's one way to do it.

```
(define-prefix-command 'space-map)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<SPC>") space-map)                                    

(define-prefix-command 'space-d-map)
(define-key space-map "d" space-d-map)                                    

(define-key space-d-map "j" 'evilem-motion-next-line)
```

Comment: It has to do with the way Vim works. We have our prefixes and keys, Vim has arguments, operators, and objects. In vim you say `3dw`: argument is `3`, the action is `delete`, and the object is `words`. In Vim, `3dw` does the same thing as `d3w`. Your answer does not take into account that the `d` is significant, it will just move the point, but not delete the region. That's why this problem is stickier than usual.

Answer (score 1):

Mmh. But `SPC` in your example is *not* like a counter. It rather acts as a leader key for `j`: `SPC j` becomes a new unit, a motion that does "something related to `j`, but more advanced" (as a mnemonic), and is bound to `#'evilem-motion-next-line`. And - you don't usually break a `leader-key` combination in the same way you'd use a counter (what I'm saying is - I don't *expect* a leader to work the same way a counter does).

That said, what you want (with vim grammar power) translates (for me) as:
 "Create a different *operation*, and map it to `SPC d`" - one that understands the `j` motion (and others). If done properly, it can happen that `SPC d` `j` will do the same thing as `d` `SPC j` :)

Although, IMHO, the "Vim way" would be to have `SPC d` `j` perform *another* operation. So that one can also type `SPC d` `SPC j` for example, with a meaningful result. So, instead of the redundancy (`SPC d` `j` = `d` `SPC j`), more functionality (`SPC d` `j` != `d` `SPC j`).

Although, I think in Emacs you probably *can* implement the leader key as a counter, since the counter is also a custom Evil implementation.

Comment: I'm doing this for [evil-easymotion](https://github.com/PythonNut/evil-easymotion), where `SPC` means _I really want a count, but I'd like to enter it visually_. So the interpretation of `SPC` is like a placeholder for the count you'll enter later. You'll do `SPC dft` and look at which `t` is the one you want and teleport there (regardless of the number of `t`s between)

Comment: You define what you  want, no need to feel constrained by "Vim-like" rules :). For me, it's not the same, *logically*, to do an operation **n** times on a motion/text-object, or to do a single operation on a range of **n** motions/text-objects (i.e. `3dw` may have the same effect as `d3w`, but nothing guarantees that, for custom operations/text-objects, `n operation text-object` == `operation n text-object`). For example, a "trim" operation could remove spaces for the beginning and end of a range: if I do "3 times trim a  line", this is different (and it's ok) than "trim a range of 3 lines".

Comment: indeed. I just haven't thought of something clever to do with the alternate meaning. easymotions are super motions. What is a super operator? In the meantime, I'd rather have the prefix modifier as an option instead of leaving it unbound. My fingers find it slightly easier to type, and my mind seems to prefer declaring the use of the grenade launcher up-front.

Comment: Heh - It's high time for an *easyoperator* plugin then :)