# Proper way to change prefix key for minor-mode map?

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode, prefix-keys

The package `HideShow` (`hs-minor-mode`) defines some key bindings with prefix key `C-c @`.

What is the proper way to change this prefix key to `C-c h`?

The new key binding should also replace the old key bindings in the menu bar items of Hide/Show menu.

I came up with this solution for remapping:

```
(setcar (cadr (lookup-key hs-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c"))) (elt (kbd "h") 0)))
```

It does what I want, but it looks wrong.

*Note:* I found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/emacs-bind-key-to-prefix) similar question. [This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13432/15749) Answer adds another Prefix but does not change the key binding shown in menu.

Comment: What do you mean by "*menu*", here? You say "*show up in the menu*" and "*key binding shown in the menu*". What menu are you talking about?

Comment: @Drew I updated this part of the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the minor-mode/package. Many make this more configurable, which doesn't seem to be true in this case. I think the simplest thing here would be to just redefine the keymap yourself instead of trying to fiddle with it. Try this

```
(setq hs-minor-mode-map
      (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
        ;; These bindings roughly imitate those used by Outline mode.
        (define-key map (kbd "C-c h C-h") 'hs-hide-block)
        (define-key map (kbd "C-c h C-s") 'hs-show-block)
        (define-key map (kbd "C-c h M-h") 'hs-hide-all)
        (define-key map (kbd "C-c h M-s") 'hs-show-all)
        (define-key map (kbd "C-c h C-l") 'hs-hide-level)
        (define-key map (kbd "C-c h C-c") 'hs-toggle-hiding)
        (define-key map [(shift mouse-2)] 'hs-mouse-toggle-hiding)
        map))
```

*Note:* this alternative needs to be done before loading of `hideshow`.

I took that from the definition of `hs-minor-mode-map` which I found with `C-h v`. Since it is defined with a `defvar` you do not need to worry about your definition being overwritten when the package loads.

## Update

Here's a shorter alternative

```
(define-key hs-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c h") (lookup-key hs-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c @")))
(define-key hs-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-c @") nil)
```

*Note:* this alternative needs to be done after `hideshow` has been loaded.

Comment: I do not want to redefine every single key binding. This seems not to be working?

Comment: What menu?...........

Comment: @Drew the Hide/Show Menu from Menu Bar

Comment: Well technically you do want to redefine all keybindings. As for the menu if you put this in your config before loading hideshow the menu will be correct.

Comment: Added another way to do this

Comment: OK, if this is set before loading of `hideshow` then the menu entries show the key bindings and this is working. But what if the package gets updated and new features are there or functions are renamed, then I have to go bug hunting.

Comment: the updated version looks good